# How to implement a mathJax into webView

Tags: android, android-webview, mathjax

I have a webView that represents a web page with MathJax equations. I heard that you can add a js script into your webView or something like that. How can I add a MathJax into my webView so equations will be represented right.

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(basicUrl, styles + content, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

The browser is a webView where I load the content. Styles is basically a string with a css styles for webView, a content is a html that I need to display. basicUrl is a url of the page that this webView represents

Comment: Can you provide some of your code outlining what you've attempted so far. That will make it easier for others to properly help you reach a resolution.

Comment: Added it into the original question.